# Why is my cursor closed in my generator function by the time I pass it to StreamingHttpResponse?

Tags: python, django, psycopg2

I have a potentially large queryset that I don't want to load into memory. It's a custom SQL statement.

`django.http.StreamingHttpResponse` takes an `iterator` (generator) argument. To avoid loading everything into memory, I'm making use of Postgres server-side cursors and `fetchmany` (though I'm yet to verify that this actually works).

Here's my generator function that I pass:

```
def queryset_generator(cursor, chunk_size=CHUNK_SIZE):
    while True:
        if cursor.closed:
            yield "cursor closed!"
            break
        rows = cursor.fetchmany(chunk_size)
        if not rows:
            break
        yield rows
```

I test if the cursor is closed because otherwise psycopg2 complains when the code afterwards tries to access a closed cursor.

And here's how I pass it in my view (simplifying the SQL):

```
with connections['mydb'].cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM foobar;")
    return StreamingHttpResponse(queryset_generator(cursor))
```

That consistently gives me

> cursor closed!

Why is the cursor closed in my generator function? If I do this in my view it works fine:

```
with connections['mydb'].cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM foobar;")
    return StreamingHttpResponse(cursor.fetchall())
```

It's also potentially noteworthy that this works fine in the shell:

```
cursor = connections['mydb'].cursor()
cursor.execute(...)
for x in StreamingHttpResponse(queryset_generator(cursor))._iterator:
    print(x)
```

Comment: Show us a traceback, not just an error message.

Comment: I had pasted the traceback, but it was unrelated (just psycopg2 complaining that the cursor was closed when I tried to access it). The error is that the cursor is closed when the generator function tries to access it, and I don't know why. I've updated the code in the question.

Comment: @tdelaney: those methods require the cursor to be open just as much as iteration does.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I made that suggestion when the author was using `fetchall`. Looks like my suggestion was taken.

Comment: @tdelaney: ah, yes, this question had changed rather radically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is the cursor closed in my generator function?

Because you exit the context manager with `return`:

```
return StreamingHttpResponse(queryset_generator(cursor))
```

This exits the `with` block, triggers the `__exit__` method on the context manager, and this method closes the cursor. The `with` statement or the context manager can't know that you just passed a reference to the `cursor` object to something else that still needs it to remain open. `with` doesn't care about references, only about the semantic block ending.

If you need to keep the cursor open until the `StreamingHttpResponse()` instance is done streaming data, you can't use the context manager around the `return` statement.

Pass in a cursor *without* using it in a context manager, and make the `queryset_generator()` function responsible for using `with` instead:

```
def queryset_generator(cursor, chunk_size=CHUNK_SIZE):
    with cursor:
        while True:
            if cursor.closed:
                yield "cursor closed!"
                break
            rows = cursor.fetchmany(chunk_size)
            if not rows:
                break
            yield rows
```

and

```
cursor = connections['mydb'].cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM foobar;")
return StreamingHttpResponse(queryset_generator(cursor))
```

Now the cursor is kept open until the `while` loop in `queryset_generator()` is done.